# Tensorflow map_fn Error PartialTensorShape: Incompatible ranks during merge

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

The following code is giving me an error which I cannot find the answer to. I am trying to apply a python function to each element of a tensor, which transforms the element into a vector of shape 3, so I can calculate a custom evaluation metric. It needs to be a Python function as it is used in other places too.

The error (log below) is `Invalid argument:  PartialTensorShape: Incompatible ranks during merge: 1 vs. 0`, and I assume it has to do with the result of map_fn and its shape. However, it only happens at runtime as if I have any other shape then it throws an error with incompatible shapes when I do model.compile(). Have I misundertood how to use map_fn? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

```
2021-04-09 12:19:31.357542: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1767] OP_REQUIRES failed at list_kernels.h:101 : Invalid argument: PartialTensorShape: Incompatible ranks during merge: 1 vs. 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 93, in <module>
    validation_data=(val_input, val_output))
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tf_models/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tf_models/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1098, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tf_models/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 780, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tf_models/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 840, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tf_models/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2829, in __call__
    return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tf_models/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1848, in _filtered_call
    cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tf_models/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1924, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tf_models/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 550, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tf_models/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 60, in quick_execute
    inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument:  PartialTensorShape: Incompatible ranks during merge: 1 vs. 0
         [[node map/TensorArrayV2Stack/TensorListStack (defined at test.py:27) ]]
         [[map_1/while/LoopCond/_50/_64]]
  (1) Invalid argument:  PartialTensorShape: Incompatible ranks during merge: 1 vs. 0
         [[node map/TensorArrayV2Stack/TensorListStack (defined at test.py:27) ]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_823]

Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function
```

This is the code to reproduce the issue, using Tensorflow 2.3.1 and Python 3.6.

```
from typing import List

import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, Flatten

INPUT_SHAPE = (2, 10, 10)


class CustomMetric(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):

    def __init__(self, name='custom_metric', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.mean_custom_metric = self.add_weight(name='mean_custom_metric', initializer='zeros', dtype=float)

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        # y_true is a probability distribution (batch, 2*10*10), so find index of most likely position
        y_pred = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
        # y_pred and y_true are both tensors with shape (batch, 1)
        print(f"y_pred: {y_pred}")

        # apply python func to convert each value to a 3D value (single scalar to vector with 3 scalars)
        # according to docs: map_fn(fn, elems).shape = [elems.shape[0]] + fn(elems[0]).shape.
        # So: elems.shape[0] == batch | fn(elems[0]).shape == 3,
        # error happens when trying to do anything with the result of map_fn below
        y_true_positions = tf.map_fn(self.wrapper, y_true, fn_output_signature=tf.float32)
        y_pred_positions = tf.map_fn(self.wrapper, y_pred, fn_output_signature=tf.float32)
        # y_true_positions, y_pred_positions: tensors with shape (batch, 3)
        print(f"y_true_positions: {y_true_positions}")

        # do something with y_true_positions and y_pred_positions
        y_final = y_true_positions
        mean = tf.reduce_sum(y_final)

        print('---')
        self.mean_custom_metric.assign(mean)

    def result(self):
        return self.mean_custom_metric

    def reset_states(self):
        self.mean_custom_metric.assign(0.0)

    def wrapper(self, x):
        # x: tensor with shape (1,)
        print(f"x: {x}")

        result = tf.py_function(python_function, [int(x)], tf.float32)
        # result is a tensor of shape unknown
        print(f"result: {result}")
        result.set_shape(tf.TensorShape(3))
        # result: tensor with shape (3,)
        print(f"result: {result}")

        return result


def python_function(index: int) -> List[float]:
    # dummy function
    return [0, 0, 0]


# dummy model
block_positions = Input(shape=(*INPUT_SHAPE, 1), dtype=tf.float32)

block_positions_layer = Flatten()(block_positions)
target_output_layer = Dense(128, activation='relu')(block_positions_layer)

target_output = Dense(np.prod(INPUT_SHAPE), activation='softmax', name='regions')(target_output_layer)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(
    inputs=[block_positions],
    outputs=(target_output))

custom_metric = CustomMetric()
model.compile(
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
    optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
    metrics=['accuracy', custom_metric])

print(model.summary())

# placeholder data
train_input = np.zeros(shape=(100, *INPUT_SHAPE), dtype=np.float32)
train_output = np.zeros(shape=(100, 1), dtype=np.int32)

val_input = np.zeros(shape=(100, *INPUT_SHAPE), dtype=np.float32)
val_output = np.zeros(shape=(100, 1), dtype=np.int32)

history = model.fit(
    train_input, train_output, epochs=10, verbose=1,
    validation_data=(val_input, val_output))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after a while. The `wrapper` function was returning a tensor of shape (3,), whereas the `map_fn` was applied over a tensor of shape (batch, 1). I don't fully understand why, but it seems that `map_fn` requires a return tensor of shape (batch, 1,) and not `fn(elems[0]).shape` as the documentation suggests.

Changing the line:
`result.set_shape(tf.TensorShape(3))`
for
`result = tf.reshape(tf.concat(result, 1), (1, 3))` in `wrapper`
so that the return value is (1, 3) instead of (3) fixed the issue. After `map_fn`, you end up with a tensor of shape (batch, 1, 3), which I reshaped to be (batch, 3).